# MDS LastChgUserName

Tags: master-data-services

We have been using MDS for a couple of years now and we have noticed that the LastChgUserName field isn't always populated (i.e. its NULL) anyone else notice this or have any idea why this is happening? This is a field that is supposed to be auto populated by MDS and is needed for troubleshooting/tracking. Note: the LastChgDateTime is always populated. I checked if the Excel addin was causing the issue and it doesn't seem to be. Also the issue isn't doesn't seem to be occurring when the record is created. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Well I dug through the stored procs and the stored proc that is used to load data programmatically into MDS hard codes the user ID to a 0 and there aren't any users with and ID of zero (select * from mdm.tblUser) and that is what is causing the LastChgUserName to be a NULL. I verified this by modifying the stored proc to take a user ID as a param and sure enough the LastChgUserName gets populated....

Answer (score 0):

The user from under which the MS web application starts (SQL Server 2019 Master Data Services Configuration Manager - Web Configuration) has an expired/changed password or is blocked.